Backend Service doesn't receive "&" when using NGINX as reverse proxy
I'm using NGINX as reverse proxy, with dynamic mapping to forward the request to the correct backend.
Here is my map directive
map $arg_action $backend {    
"~^nginx/.*" nginx-web;
"~^httpd/.*" httpd-web;
}

I'm proxying the traffic to the correct upstream by the following:
location /data {    
proxy_redirect off;     
proxy_bypass http://$backend/$arg_action; 
}

The APIs I'm triggering are:
 /data?action=httpd/v1/CompareAnimals?animal=cat&bird=high

The httpd service gets the following API:
httpd/v1/CompareAnimals?animal=cat, NGINX will not bypass anything after "&" character

How can I make the httpd service to get the full API when I trigger it? such as :
httpd/v1/CompareAnimals?animal=cat&bird=high

and not only
httpd/v1/CompareAnimals?animal=cat


Seems like you should use proxy_pass over proxy_bypass, and just add $args and $is_args variable provided by NGINX
location /data {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://$backend/$arg_action$is_args$args;
}

